# Silverlight NavigationFramework is not changing address bar (no hashtags are displayed) when navigating

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am using Navigation framework and basicly got one frame that is used for navigation.
I have tried playing with  `mainFrame.JournalOwnership` cause I thought maybe changing it might be connected to this but nothing changes.

Since navigation related classes structure is quite small I am a little puzzled here about what am I doing wrong cause I cannot think of anything else I can change to make navigation work.

I am not using Navigation template, I use it free style much like in this video tutorial http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/navigation-framework/ if someone might wonder.

Thanks in advance. Really struggling with it. Please help

I have tried to reproduce bug in another solution by using just my mainframe page and calling simple navigatate to empty test page and it worked fine so I now got new questions.

Maybe there is a way that my SL page HTML is disabling hash tags being set by navigation framework?

EDIT: I have tested putting my working test XAP on my html page instead of my whole application that is not working, and it didnt update hashtags on this page. So now its clear something is wrong with html page, what could be it?

Comment: I have tried both IE and Chrome, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out the problem.
Turns out the key here was iframe used by silverlight for using this operation,
after I added following code to my aspx page it started to work like magic.

```
<iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
```

as stated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The very act of setting JournalOwnership = JournalOwnership.OwnsJournal says to SL that navigation history is maintained elsewhere.  In other words, the minor URL changes that are used to track history are no longer utilized.  Remember navigating a frame in a SL Navigation Application doesn't move off the page, but it does update the URI bookmark # to maintain state in very much the way AJAX maintains history.  If you SL app really "left the page/URI" then your app would have to reload completely.  It is working as prescribed whether you are using the Navigation Template or now.  Changing "frames" is literally just loading up a UserControl type and putting the content into an area of the existing SL control.

Comment: It doesn't update hashtags , i say no changes and I mean that address stays the same , no # is displayed at all, just index.aspx page that hosts silverlight (example name). I understand that changing frames is loading controls in other controls, however beside that it should update addressbar hashtags , and it doesn't. So the question is how to make it do? Where to look?

Comment: I never said it would update Hash Tags.  Not sure if you're not understanding what I said above.  Setting OwnsJournal means no Hash Tag changes.   That's what you specified with this setting.  Unset it or don't set it.

Comment: well since nothing is updating hashtags maybe I dont understand how exactly should OwnsJournal work, but it doesn't update hashtags with or without OwnJournal set.

Comment: ok I guess you are right and it should be working & updating hashtags on default auto mode, but it doesn't